# How do I create an HTML element with attributes and events using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, element

I was working on a school project on discovering JavaScript and am stuck with Element creating, so I would like to know how do I need to implement this.

Comment: Theres this wonderful thing called google that will find many results or tutorials that will give you an idea about how to do this.

Comment: How about showing us where you're stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Create element:

```
var element = document.createElement('table');
```

Adding attribute:

```
element.setAttribute( "id", "table1" );
```

Comment: The `setAttribute` example is a bad one. One should just use `element.id = "table1"`

Comment: Well, first of all thank you for your answer !
But I want to add some events in the element

Comment: document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
     alert('Клик')
}

Comment: I want to make something like this : 
<div ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> <img id="1" src="splitted\1.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="80"></div>

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to create element and set attribute.
**Creating Element**
first way of creating element:

```js
let nameOfElement = document.createElement("tabel")
```

second way of creating element:

```js
let elementName = `<tabel></tabel>`
```

**Now setting attributes**
First way of setting attribute:

```js
nameOfElement.setAttribute("id", "the-value")
```

Second way of setting attribute:

```js
let creatingElement = `<tabel id="value"></tabel>`
```